# Testing Trend Stationarity against Stationarity

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, arima, stationarity, trend

I am trying to find a test where null hypothesis is that the series is trend stationary. I can assume that the trend is linear if that is going to help. So the series for null hypothesis is given by:
$y_t = a + bt + x_t$

Where $x_t$ is a stationary time series which we take it to have zero mean without loss of generality.

Comment: Can you please clarify on what trend stationarity is?

Comment: @Galen https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trend-stationary_process#:~:text=In%20the%20statistical%20analysis%20of,not%20have%20to%20be%20linear.

Comment: Thank you! I had been using this concept for quite a while but didn't have a term for it.

Answer (score 1):

The Kwiatkowski-Phillips-Schmidt-Shin test is a unit root test that actually has the unit root as the alternative (so not $I(0)$ or $I(1)$), and trend-stationarity as the null.

Can you also assume the absence of seasonality? In my experience, series that contain multiple periodicities can mess with unit root tests. The (augumented) Dickey-Fuller test can get pretty confused. e.g. on completely unprocessed temperature data over a year, a very nonstationary process but with complicated periodicities, it can fail to reject the null of stationarity.

Edit: Hmm, if the only 2 cases are stationarity or linear trend-stationarity with the latter as the null, then that's the same as equivalence testing $b \neq 0$ on the regression coefficient of a simple linear regression of the series on time.

Because in this case the errors are stationary and thus can be autocorrelated, you'll have to use HAC robust standard errors though, such as Newey-West. Typical equivalence testing procedures like TOST do require you to specify a range around $b = 0$ that is still consistent with the alternative. (i.e. an effect size that is small enough to be unimportant).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want to test whether $b\neq 0$ or not. I am very confident that there is no unit root in the data I am dealing with so I believe KPSS is not useful. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Bronsteinx I didn't realize the presence of a unit root was already ruled out, I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks again, I read about Newey-West. It seems that this basically solve problem when you use autoregressive models but when you have a moving average part you cant use it. Am I missing something?